# Запрос на разницу между последним и предпоследним одинаковым значением mysql

Tags: mysql

Помогите пожалуйста , есть таблица с двумя столбцами `id` и `number` , подскажите пожалуйста как сделать запрос к примеру на число `50` которое находится по `id=60`,`id=22` и `id=3` , в обратной последовательности.. Как грамотно составить запрос на разницу строк или id последнего числа `id=60` и предпоследнего `id=22`

Comment: Что значит разница строк?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, нужно что-то такое:

```
SELCT ((SELECT id 
    FROM table
    WHERE number = 50
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1
) - (SELECT id 
    FROM table
    WHERE number = 50
    ORDER BY id DESC
    LIMIT 1,1
)) as result
```

Comment: удивительно. я не понял вопроса, соответственно, не понимаю, про что вы все отвечаете. Теперь осталось только, чтобы один из ответов приняли как правильный.

Comment: Спасибо , сколько сидел думал а о LIMIT 1,1 совсем забыл ))) вы правильно поняли нужно , выводится предыдущее значение)) а как вывести посредством php результат ?

Comment: всё) разобрался)) спасибо огромное)

Comment: @splash58 я тоже не понял) решил догадаться)))

Comment: Поздравляю с победой в "битве экстрасенсов" =)

Answer (score 0):

Запрос на число 50 с обратной последовательностью id:
SELECT id, number FROM my_table WHERE number='50' ORDER BY id DESC

Запрос на айди максимального числа:
SELECT id FROM my_table ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1